# SQLZOO - Lots of trailing 0s when using CONCAT with ROUND

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Doing a problem in SQLZOO: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkxnr.png)

Everything makes sense up to the point when I use CONCAT to add the '%' at the end of the rounded number. Suddenly the query returns with lots of meaningless trailing 0s after the decimal.

My code:

```
SELECT name, 
CONCAT(ROUND(100*population/(SELECT population
                          FROM world
                         WHERE name = 'Germany'),0),'%') AS percentage
FROM world
WHERE continent = 'Europe'
```

The result:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGUXP.png)
The result without the CONCAT function:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeNAP.png)

Comment: Can't be replicated, see https://dbfiddle.uk/f4mE7sZV

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information directly to your question preferably as editable text